# Mock CSVReader with mockito and multible return values

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I wan't to mock the CSVReader. So my mock should return a new array each time, this should be generic.
the last value should be null.

ex

```
nextLine() -> ["a","b","c"]
nextLine() -> ["a","b","c"]
nextLine() -> null
```

My MockClass:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.sun.javafx.beans.annotations.NonNull;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class CSVReaderMock {
    CSVReader reader;
    private boolean linesCorrectInitialized;

    public CSVReaderMock()
    {
        reader = mock(CSVReader.class);
    }

    public CSVReaderMock returnLines(@NonNull List<String> lines) {
        // the last value has to be null
        lines.add(null);
        try {
            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] lineArr = null;
                if (line != null) {
                    lineArr = line.split(",");
                }
                when(reader.readNext()).thenReturn(lineArr);
            }
            linesCorrectInitialized = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
        return this;
    }

    public CSVReader create() {
        if (!linesCorrectInitialized) { throw new RuntimeException("lines are not initialized correct"); }
        return reader;
    }

}
```

and here a testcase (i only writed to check my mock builder):

```
@Test
public void testImportLines() throws Exception {
    CSVReader reader;
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("some,lines,for,testing");
    reader = new CSVReaderMock().returnLines(list).create();


    System.out.println(reader.readNext()); // should return [Ljava.lang.String;@xxxx with conent-> ["some","lines","for","testing"]
    System.out.println(reader.readNext()); // should return null
}
```

the actual output is :

```
null
null
```

So my question is, how can i pass a list of return values without knowing in advance how the list will look? I know i could pass the "csv lines" via `.thenReturn(line1,line2,line3)` but this will break my approach.

Comment: `line.split(";");` did you intend to split on `,` ?

Comment: @DeepakBala of course, i've fied it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito has a [ReturnsElementsOf](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/answers/ReturnsElementsOf.html) Answer for just such an occasion.

> Returns elements of the collection. Keeps returning the last element forever. Might be useful on occasion when you have a collection of elements to return.

So now you just need to prepare the elements and then pass that in. Because the null call will need to be added at the very end, it'll keep you from reusing the CSVReaderMock builder, but that's the same whether or not you use the answer.

```
List<String[]> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

public CSVReaderMock returnLines(@NonNull List<String> lines) {
  try {
    for (String line : lines) {
      String[] lineArr = null;
      if (line != null) {
        lineArr = line.split(",");
      }
      returnList.add(lineArr);
    }
    linesCorrectInitialized = true;
  } catch (IOException e) { /* ... */ };
  return this;
}

public CSVReader create() {
  if (!linesCorrectInitialized) { /* ... */ }
  // Return null repeatedly after all stubs are exhausted.
  returnList.add(null);
  when(reader.readNext()).thenAnswer(new ReturnsElementsOf(returnList));
  return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain the return values into a single when() result by using the OngoingStubbing reference, e.g:

```
    Iterator<String> ls = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
    OngoingStubbing<String> stubbing = when(ls.next());

    for(String s: new String[] { "ABC", "DEF" }) {
        stubbing = stubbing.thenReturn(s);
    }

    System.out.println(ls.next());
    System.out.println(ls.next());
```

... prints "ABC", then "DEF".